# Meteor mobile build vs having a phonegap browser

Tags: meteor

Why is the difference between using a simple phonegap browser app pointed at your site vs using meteor's mobile build options?

Answer (score 0):

> a simple phonegap browser app pointed at your site

Not sure exactly why you would be ready to use this option, compared to a simple shortcut / link to your site, or even an "installable" Web App.

Anyway, since you point at your site, it means you require an Internet connection whenever you open your app, and you are limited by what a website can access to on your device.

> meteor's mobile build options

It becomes similar to a native app (it is actually called a "hybrid" app), so you can use it totally offline, and you can access more device functionalities (file system, notifications, etc.).

Nothing really specific to Meteor here, it is rather why using a hybrid app v.s. a shortcut.

In the end, you should base your decision on your requirements:

- Do you need to access your app while offline?
- Is your app primary functionality accessing "real time" content that makes no sense using your app while offline? (like news, forums, etc.)
- Do you need to access specific device functionalities, that are not accessible by a normal website?

You should have plenty resources on that topic on the Internet.

---

Your question might rather be: what is the difference between a standard hybrid app (typically built through Cordova / Phonegap) and one built through Meteor?

In that case, you are asking what Meteor brings specifically? (as it uses Cordova under the hood to build the app)

First of all, you have all advantages of Meteor framework for normal website (minimongo, isomorphic methods, etc.)

You also have by default the Hot Code Push functionality. You can also set it up on your Cordova / Phonegap app, but you will have to configure it yourself, whereas Meteor does everything for you.

Finally, you might benefit from Meteor packages that bring Cordova plugin + client code + server code, something unique to Meteor as it is a full-stack framework.